# Matlab import B&W 16-bit tiff then plot?

Tags: matlab, tiff

I have a 16-bit tiff that is b&w. It has no color mapping.

I import it like the following:

```
Tiff = imread('MyImage.tif')
```

That gives me a Variable with a value 'single' named Tiff.  It is just a grid/matrix of intensity values for each pixel.

I have tried then using

```
image(Tiff);
```

But I end up with an image that is all Yellow.

If I do

```
imagesc(Tiff);
```

Then it kind of works, but its not grayscale, it is more like a heat map.

How do I plot the tiff on a graph? I want to be able to then then graph other lines on top of that tiff image.

Comment: Try `imshow(Tiff, []);`. In case it doesn't work, find a way to upload 'MyImage.tif' file to file hosting site, and post a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[I,cmap] = imread('your_image.tif');
img  = ind2rgb(I,cmap);
```

To plot something on top of your image you can do this:

```
figure, imshow(img);
hold on;
plot(your_x_data,your_y_data); % or whatever yo want plot on top that image.
```

Comment: Nope, I get an error.  'Index exceeds matrix dimensions'.  When I do [I,cmap] the cmap value comes out empty/blank.

Comment: Ohh!! I don't know whats goin on :(  if possible, could you please upload your image in the question itself.